# Scheduling .sh on windows

Tags: windows, bash, windows-10, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Recently I downloaded Windows 10 preview for developers with build 1432 that has Ubuntu bash.

I've been trying to schedule jobs in crontab but so far it failed and it's not working. I want to schedule an `*.sh` script to run. So far nothing is happening.

My crontab entry looks like this:

```
26 * * * * /mnt/h/Filmy/du.sh
```

And the script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /mnt/h/Filmy

du -s | tr -d "\t\r." >> du.txt
```

I know that is just BETA of this yet but maybe someone has a solution for that.
Is there any workaround to schedule .sh scripts on Win10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Windows Insiders Build 17046](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/background-task-support-in-wsl/) you are able to run cron jobs in the background even if the terminal is closed.

To make sure cron is actually running you can type `service cron status`. If it isn't currently running then type `service cron start` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Now it works !!! thank you man :) I lost all the hope after these years

Answer (score 0):

WSL doesn't yet support running background / scheduled tasks without an open Bash prompt: As soon as you close your last open Bash console, WSL tears down all running Linux processes.

We'll be working to improve this scenario in a future release.